# Get top 10 records from each parent category in a single array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 2 collection- 'video' & 'category', I have to join them and show columns from both the collection then i have to fetch 10 video_id of each parent category in single array. I am attaching the query which i wrote

fetching 10 video_id of each parent category-

```
db.vid_v2.aggregate([ 
  { $match: {"parent_category": { $exists: true, $ne: null } } },
  {$group: {_id: "$parent_category"}}
]).forEach(function(doc){
  print(db.vid_v2.find({parent_category: doc._id},{parent_category :1 , video_id: 1}).sort({date:1}).limit(10))})
```

the above query is working but the output is in multiple array, I need the output in single array with joining the video collection with category collection and showing category_name in the output

ps - video_id and parent_category are from video collection,

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `$lookup` or populate?

Comment: I am already using lookup for join two collection and it is giving expected data, but need to join the below query with previous mention query in question.

db.vid_v2.aggregate([{ $match: {"parent_category": { $exists: true, $ne: null } } },{$lookup: { from: "category", localField: "category_id", foreignField: "parent_category", as: "cats"}},{$project: {parent_category :1 , video_id: 1, name:1, created_date: 1, category_name: "$cats.category_name"}},{$sort: {date:1}},{$limit : 10}])